Cannot Run .jar Executable after Building JavaFX Application
I am trying to build a .jar executable from a JavaFX Application in IntelliJ Idea. The .jar file is not running, and displays an error message saying, "A Java Exception has occurred." when I run the .jar file with Java(TM) Platform SE Binary as seen below:
enter image description here
When I run the .jar file with OpenJDK Platform Binary, I get the little buffer circle next to my cursor for a split second, but the application does not load.
The program runs perfectly in IntelliJ.
I believe my problem is stemming from something in my MANIFEST.MF file or pom.xml file, since I have seen other solutions tinker with those files. I have already checked that my main class is the correct class and path in pom.xml:
<mainClass>
   com.example.vocleadteachersalaryapp/com.example.vocleadteachersalaryapp.Main
</mainClass>

And I have checked that my main class is the correct class and path in MANIFEST.MF:
Main-Class: com.example.vocleadteachersalaryapp.Main

I am building the .jar file with the same main class:
enter image description here
Here is my main class:
package com.example.vocleadteachersalaryapp;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        IntroMenu.run(stage);
    }

}

I do not have a launch() function in my main class because it spits out an error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application launch must not be called on the JavaFX Application Thread
I have tried using a public static void main(String[] args) function that calls the launch() function, and that runs fine, but I receive the same output when trying to run the .jar file.
Additionally, I have tried to build the .jar using a JavaFX application type, as a seen below.
enter image description here
You can see in the image that it spits out an error saying "Can't build artifact - fx:deploy is not available in this JDK". After researching this a bit, I have found from this post that this feature is broken.
I am using the Temurin-22 JDK.
UPDATE: The "Sources" and "JavaDocs" display a red path for almost every library (from the one I have selected in the image and down). https://i.sstatic.net/BNorngzu.png
Could this be the source of my problem?

What error do you see in the terminal (i.e., when executing java [options] -jar <jarfile>)?

The JavaFX Ant tasks are no longer supported.  They were replaced by the jlink tool which comes with every JDK.  I assume this plugin is what does it in Maven, though I haven’t used it myself.

@Slaw This is when I run the .jar through the out folder:
`PS C:\Users\jacob\IdeaProjects\Voc Lead Teacher Salary App\out\artifacts\VocLeadInstructorSalaryApp_jar> java Main -jar VocLeadInstructorSalaryApp.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class Main`

And what does java -jar VocLeadInstructorSalaryApp.jar give you (notice that doesn't include the Main part).

@VGR I have JLink installed. Upon running JLink (clicking on it in the Maven widget thing to the right of my screen) This error message pops up: Exit code: 1 Command line was: jlink [--module-path, [VERY LONG PATH] --add-modules, javafx.base,javafx.graphicsEmpty,javafx.baseEmpty,org.apiguardian.api,javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml,javafx.fxmlEmpty,javafx.controlsEmpty,com.example.vocleadteachersalaryapp, --output, C:\Users\jacob\IdeaProjects\Voc Lead Teacher Salary App\target\maven-jlink\default]
Does not make sense; I have most modules in module-info, but they still display.

@Slaw I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/example/vocleadteachersalaryapp/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 66.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
Does this mean that my JRE is out of date?

It means your application was compiled with Java 22 (or Java 23 with --release 22), but you're trying to execute it with Java 8. So, yes, it means the JRE you're trying to execute the application with is too old. A JRE can only run code compiled to target its own version or lower, never higher. Does javac -version and java -version give you the same version?

@Slaw Yes, I get the same version: javac 22.0.2 and java version "22.0.2" 2024-07-16 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 22.0.2+9-70) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0.2+9-70, mixed mode, sharing)
